# Filter duplicates by property and max value in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Quick (and most probably) simple question.

Given the following `List<Job>`:

```
Job(requesterId: 1, offer: 100)
Job(requesterId: 1, offer: 150)
Job(requesterId: 1, offer: 200)
Job(requesterId: 2, offer: 100)
Job(requesterId: 3, offer: 100)
Job(requesterId: 3, offer: 110)
```

I want to be able to filter its duplicates based on `requesterId`, but also based on the highest `offer`, so that I end up with a `List<Job>` containing the highest offers per `requesterId` like this:

```
Job(requesterId: 1, offer: 200)
Job(requesterId: 2, offer: 100)
Job(requesterId: 3, offer: 110)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: do you want the highest offer per `requesterId` then ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Indeed what you said, the highest offer per `requesterId`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val sortedList = list
    .groupBy { it.requesterId }
    .map { it.value.maxBy { it.offer } }
```

Comment: Thanks. `maxBy` returns an optional so the final list will be `List<Job?>` instead of the `List<Job>` my question was asking for. But I'll mark your answer as accepted if no one else answers this taking optionals into account.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any null values, just take mapNotNull

```
val sortedList = list
    .groupBy { it.requesterId }
    .mapNotNull { it.value.maxByOrNull{obj -> obj.offer } }
```